# changing .emacs to use IronPython.exe and using code completion for IronPython modules?

Tags: python, emacs, cygwin, ironpython

I configured my Emacs for code completion and other help using this [link](http://www.enigmacurry.com/2009/01/21/autocompleteel-python-code-completion-in-emacs/) (from another question here on SO). I am a complete newbie to emacs.

Can anyone tell me what should I change so it (rope, ropemacs, pymacs, yasnippet etc) picks up symbols of IronPython modules for code completion and snippets.

Also I want to map:

C-x RET - to invoke IronPython.exe and not Python.exe (any clue on how to do that)

PS I am using Emacs with Cygwin on XP machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `python-command` contains the path of the python interpreter to be run.  By default, this is usually just set to "python", which runs the first python in your path.

Try changing it to point directly to the IronPython exe file:

```
(setq python-command "C:/Program Files/IronPython 2.6/ipy.exe")
```

Comment: For pymacs, you'll also need to set the PYMACS_PYTHON environment variable to the IronPython executable as well.